# How to remove character from string by position number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I have a string like this:

```
var str = "this is a **test";
```

Now I want to remove those two stars (positions `10` and `11`). And I want this:

```
var newstar = "this is a test";
```

Again, I want to remove them using the number of their position. How can I do that?

Comment: @AvinashRaj This is what I guess: `str.slice(`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use `string.replace` also.

```
> var str = "this is a **test";
> str.replace(/^(.{10})../, '$1')
'this is a test'
```

`^(.{10})` captures the first 10 characters and the following `..` matches the 11th and 12th character. So by replacing all the matched characters with the captured chars will give you the expected output.

If you want to satisfy the position condition plus the character codition then your regex must be,

```
str.replace(/^(.{10})\*\*/, '$1')
```

This would replace the two stars only if it was placed at pos 11 and 12.

You may use variable also inside the regex using `RegExp` constructor.

```js
var str = "this is a ***test";
var pos = 10
var num = 3
alert(str.replace(new RegExp("^(.{" + pos + "}).{" + num + "}"), '$1'))
```

Comment: Well using `..` is really interesting to me .. I enjoyed thanks +1. But in reality those characters arenot the same .. May you please also tell me how can I do that without using `..` ?

Comment: @stack `.` matches any character except line breaks. If you want to match also the linebreaks then use `[\s\S]` instead of `.`

Comment: JUst check with this example, `var str = "this is a ?ktest";`

Comment: Can I use a variable instead of `10` ?  I don't know why it doesn't work for me ..

Comment: I'm sorry to ping you again .. but may you please tell me how can I do that for three characters? `10`, `11`, `12` ? I added `..` again but it doesn't work as well, like this : `"^(.{" + num + "})...."`

Comment: use three dots `"^(.{" + num + "})..."` or replace three dots with `.{3}`. Same as above, save the num of chars you wnat to remove in a variable

Comment: Look, I'm working on my thesis, Now I want to mention multiple solutions to solve a problem. this makes my thesis powerful. So if you have some free time (or maybe later, no hurry) please and please add to your solution doing that by `.slice()` function. *(if it is possible)*

Answer (score 0):

You can use .slice twice

```
var str = "this is a **test";
str =  str.slice(0, 10)+ str.slice(11);
str=str.slice(0, 10)+str.slice(11);

'this is a test'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
var str = "this is a **test";

var ref = str.replace(/\*/g, '');     //it will remove all occurrences of *

console.log(ref)   //this is a test
```